# forEach unexpected token adding new property to existing array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to add a new proeprrty call total_days calculate using date_from and date_to but my forEach got an expected token error.

```
let applicants = [{
    date_from: '2017-05-05',
    date_to: '2017-05-10'
},{
    date_from: '2017-05-08',
    date_to: '2017-05-12'
}]

calculateDays = applicants.forEach(obj => 
    applicants['total_days'] = (obj.date_from).diff(obj.date_to, 'days')+1;
)
```

No clue what's wrong here.

Comment: `calculateDays` will be undefined anyway, because that's what forEach returns - and `applicants['total_days']` will be the result of the last loop only

Comment: not only that, you have a semicolon to much `)+1;` <---

Comment: the unexpected token is the `;` - the only semicolon you've used is the one place it can not be - and two places it "should" be, you haven't used one!!! WTF

Comment: @JaromandaX what should I do? I'm lost. I simply remove calculateDays because it is not needed here, but regard my second mistake I have no clue on that.

Comment: remove the `;`? because that's the unexpected token

Comment: please add the wanted result. it looks like, you add a named key to an array, which does not appear in the output. if you like to get the difference inside of the objects, you could use `obj['total_days'] = (obj.date_from).diff(obj.date_to, 'days')+1`

Comment: what is `.diff`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to add a new property to all objects, you could use `obj` as variable with a new property.

```
applicants.forEach(obj => obj.total_days = obj.date_from.diff(obj.date_to, 'days') + 1);
//                        ^^^
```

Comment: sort that out but my day different is not working. https://jsfiddle.net/szfzysm2/

Comment: what answer do you expect?

Comment: ah my mistake getting the wrong obj, sorted out now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't exactly clarify what you wanted but I tried to take a guess by your code.

My guess is that you wanted to create a new array of applicants from the old array of applicants but in the new array, you wanted to add a property to each object in that array that is the difference in days of the two dates.

To do so, you can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map each item from your array to a new array.

I'm also using [`Object.assign` to clone each object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Cloning_an_object) so that the original array is unmodified.

I'm also parsing the date strings into number. The parsed number is the number of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC. If I take the difference of the two numbers and divide that be the `millisecondsInADay` then I'll get how many days elapsed in between.

The result is then stored into a new array `calculateDays`.

Let me know if you need more clarification.

```js
let applicants = [{
  date_from: '2017-05-05',
  date_to: '2017-05-10'
}, {
  date_from: '2017-05-08',
  date_to: '2017-05-12'
}]

const millisecondsInADay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

const calculateDays = applicants.map(obj => Object.assign({}, obj, {
  total_days: ((
    Date.parse(obj.date_to) - Date.parse(obj.date_from)
   ) / millisecondsInADay) + ' days'
}));

console.log(calculateDays);
```